# changing text in a website using JavaScript and tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

So basically I'm trying to change a text of a website using `javascript` with `tampermonkey` but I ran into a problem. Basically when I type my code on the console it works but doesn't work when I inject into the web page.

```
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include        

// ==/UserScript==
 (function() {
    let seconds = 3;
    setTimeout( () => {
        let my_div = document.getElementById("win0divSTDNT_ENRL_SSV1_CRSE_GRADE_OFF$0");
        my_div.innerHTML = 'B';
        my_div.innerText = 'B';
    }, seconds * 1e3);
})();`
```

Answer (score 1):

check  Ajax load HTML content

check Dynamic HTML Rendering

use  setTimeout

```
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    var my_div = 
     document.getElementById("win0divSTDNT_ENRL_SSV1_CRSE_GRADE_OFF$0")
     my_div.innerHTML = 'B'
   }, 3000);
```

Comment: can you please write me an sample code that i can run it would be very helpful

Comment: uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. it works on devtools but not on greasymonkey

Comment: chanch 3000 ms to higher value and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it runs your code in 3 seconds

```
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include        https://saprd.my.uh.edu/

// ==/UserScript==
 (function() {
    let seconds = 3;
    setTimeout( () => {
        let my_div = document.getElementById("win0divSTDNT_ENRL_SSV1_CRSE_GRADE_OFF$0");
        my_div.innerHTML = 'B';
        my_div.innerText = 'B';
    }, seconds * 1e3);
})();`
```

Comment: Can you paste here a code from line: // ==/UserScript==

Comment: im sorry im new to coding so im confused on what you are asking ?

Comment: If you are new to coding I definetely recommend you to check userscripting tutorials, like "how to run userscript on browser", check youtube as well, it helped me a lot. By now I would like to see your whole code sample what you are trying to do, because tampermonkey uses predefined lines like //@name //@match

Comment: look at my edit made above i basically copy and pasted your code on the console and on tampermonkey and it didn't work

Comment: I edited as well, can you post the whole code please like I did?

Comment: Okay mate, try to edit line 6, include, // @include      https://saprd.my.uh.edu/

Comment: Do not forget to upvote if this helped you to understand the issue or learn something new. Cheers